# Python Script open a blank Chromedriver Window

Tags: python

the code is:

```
class Chrome:
instance = ChromeClass()
session_id = instance.session_id
executor_url = instance.command_executor._url
```

this opens a blank browser window, because _url is not defined.
I import this file and the class in another python file because i need session_id in another file. When i remove instance the defination of session_id is not working anymore because the defination of instance is not set.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: When i import the python class it should not open a new instance in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to open a driver as soon as you initiate the class, don't call the function immediately.

replace `instance = ChromeClass()` with `instance = ChromeClass`

Comment: the problem is, when i import this function into python: ChromeClass has no attribute session_id